# Handling out-of-memory situation

Tags: c#

I have an object that behaves like a cache. It could fill whole available memory if needed.

I'd like to be able to give memory back to an OS on-need basis. So if there is a problem with any other allocation, VM (or GC or whoever) should ask my 'cache' to shrink before failing with OutOfMemory exception.

How can I do it in C#?

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend you to use the [built-in Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) instead of reinventing the wheel. It automatically takes care of situations like this: it will expire items based on their priority if memory starts to run low. It is also very extensible and you can easily make it distributed with popular providers such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Note that `System.Runtime.Caching` is only available in .NET 4.0 only. Other caches are available in earlier versions, such as Enterprise library, System.Web.Caching, Velocity, ...

Comment: Note: System.Runtime.Caching is only available in .Net Framework 4. Other caches are available in earlier versions, e.g., Enterprise library, System.Web.Caching.

Comment: you could name velocity (which is now part of microsoft application server - appFabric)

Comment: @ShellShock, good point. I will update my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about a configurable maximum cache size; when your cache reaches the max, you remove the oldest items from it. The max should be defined in terms that make sense for your cache, e.g, max items in the cache, max memory use etc.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question. Have you tried to play with [WeakReferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28VS.80%29.aspx)? It looks like that is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep objects in cache for a limited time, and use built-in cache.